# php can't load module extensions

Tags: php, apache, php-extension

I tried to load php modules like pgsql, but it doesn't appear in **phpinfo** page.

I changed the **php.ini** like this

```
extension = pgsql.so
```

I have the **pgsql.so** in the extension_dir .

Comment: did you restart the server after making the changes ? also try get_loaded_extensions(); it will give you an array of loaded modules..

Comment: yes i did . But they doesn't appear in phpinfo or get_loaded_extensions() array

Comment: maybe you have multiple php installations ...

Comment: i changed the php.ini located in the section i found in phpinfo() Loaded Configuration File

Comment: but i have no error in my apache log